# make multiLine Textview scrollable in ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am trying to have my multiline textview scrollable in listview but failed.
here is some code i have:

```
 myCommentTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="Comment"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:typeface="normal" />
```

after searching through SO, someone suggested this answer : (i was able to copy but forget the save the link)

```
class MyTextView extends TextView
{

  public MyTextView(Context context)
  {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
  {
    boolean ret;
    ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    if(ret)
    {
        list.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    return ret;
  }

}
```

I tried to make a custom class like this, but android studio show red underlined at line `list.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` (cannot resolve method)  and `extends TextView` (should extend android.support.v7.widget.appcompatTextView)

here is my class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;    
import java.util.List;


    public class MyTextView extends TextView {

        public MyTextView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            boolean ret;
            ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            if(ret)
            {
                List.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            }
            return ret;
        }

    }
```

I can change the textview to appCompatTextView even though i don't understand why because from the source, it seemed okay because it was the accepted answer. but still, the most important code `List.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` would remain error.

how to fix this ?

Comment: try 'android:maxLines="5" // whatever u need'.

Comment: tried it but not worked, i think the problem is the listview is taking over the focus/touch listener. so the entire list is scrolled even i touch and scroll the textview

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent indeed is the key here,

```
 View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                boolean isLarger;

                isLarger = ((TextView) v).getLineCount()
                        * ((TextView) v).getLineHeight() > v.getHeight();
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                        && isLarger) {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                } else {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        holder.comment.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```